# How to ignore dashes in XSD namespaces for classes generation using JAXB

Tags: java, maven, soap, jaxb, jax-ws

I generate classes from XSD files using JAXB.

The namespaces of XSD are mostly like:

- `http://firstsupplier.customermodule.xcompany.com/ws/datatypes/service1`
- `http://secondsupplier.customermodule.xcompany.com/ws/datatypes/service2`
- `http://secondsupplier.productmodule.xcompany.com/ws/datatypes/service3`

I have to integrate an unusual named one which has a difference `x-company` using a dash `-` character (or any similar).

- `http://firstsupplier.customermodule.x-company.com/ws/datatypes/service4`

This results in the inconsistently named packages at the `target/classes`:

```
com
\   x-company.customermodule.firstsupplier   ... ws.datatypes.service4
\   company 
    \   customermodule
        \   firstsupplier                    ... ws.datatypes.service1
        \   secondsupplier                   ... ws.datatypes.service2
    \   productmodule
        \   secondsupplier                   ... ws.datatypes.service3
```

How do I achieve the following structure using JAXWS bindings without changing explicitly the namespaces at WSDL and XSD files?

```
com.company 
\   customermodule
     \   firstsupplier      ... ws.datatypes.service1 & ws.datatypes.service4
     \   secondsupplier     ... ws.datatypes.service2 
\   productmodule
     \   secondsupplier     ... ws.datatypes.service3
```

Comment: You should define the name of your package in the configuration for the generation plugin ...